# VScode debugging with jest returns "Unexpected Token" error on imported CSS file

Tags: css, reactjs, debugging, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I debug a react app in VSCode using jest with the following configuration:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Jest",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "args": [
      "--runInBand",
      "--coverage"
    ],
    "runtimeArgs": [
      "--nolazy", "-r", "flow-remove-types/register"
    ],
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "development"
    },
    "sourceMaps": true
}
```

When I run a test where the js file imports a css file, (e.g. "import ./Bla.css"), I get the following "Unexpected token" error:

```
Test suite failed to run
    /Users/rdiaz15/yeti/service-registry-react-ui/src/main/app/src/app/TopBarView.css: Unexpected token (1:0)
      > 1 | .topbar {
          | ^
        2 |     position: fixed;
        3 |     top: 0px;
```

Why is it trying to debug my css?  How do I prevent this?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-css-modules